# Struggling to get Django server to run in virtual environment

Tags: python, django

I'm new to using Django & Python and am having some difficulty trying to get my manage.py application to run in a virtual environment.

I am receiving the following errors at the top of my models.py file:

[image]

I initially thought that this was an issue with pylint not pointing at the right environment (when I switch my Python interpretter to the one outside of the virtual environment, the pylint errors disappear); however, whenever I try to run my server, I get the following error:

```
(.venv) tjmcerlean@LAPTOP-RKLCBQLO:/mnt/c/Users/tjmce/Desktop/Git/CS50w/Project 2/commerce$ python manage.py runserverTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/mnt/c/Users/tjmce/Desktop/Git/CS50w/Project 2/commerce/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

This error appears to suggest that the virtual environment is not activated. However, I activated it using the location of the virtual environment (.venv/bin/activate) and saw that the bash terminal now displays (.venv):

[image]

Additionally, when using the (pip freeze) command, I can see that Django is installed within the virtual environment too:

[image]

I'm lost as to why the server won't run and would really appreciate any advice.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you name you project `django` by any chance?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: What's in your PYTHONPATH variable?

Comment: did you try to reinstall Django or recreate virtualenv

Comment: Yes I have recreated the virtual environment and reinstalled Django, with no luck. I'm getting the same error with a fresh environment.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `django.__file__` in activated env reveals the real path:

```sh
python -c "import django; print(django.__file__)"
```

it should looks like /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py
then re-check PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Maybe you've installed 2 Django in venv and system-wide but in some of them there is no `db`. And also remove all of `*.pyc` files in your working folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When running the code I'm getting the following error: 

(.venv) tjmcerlean@LAPTOP-RKLCBQLO:/mnt/c/Users/tjmce/Desktop/Git/CS50w/Project 2/commerce$ python3 -c "import django; print(django.__file__)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/c/Users/tjmce/Desktop/Git/CS50w/Project 2/commerce/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils'

Comment: So you have `django` module without any submodules it should have. Then there is a django.py or django.pyc somewhere in your PYTHONPATH that's loaded instead of real django. Run "pip uninstall django" and remove all "django.py*" and "django/__init__.py"

Comment: I've just deleted my virtual environment as I couldn't seem to uninstall Django from it, just seemed to freeze up in VSCode after waiting for over 5 minutes. Will setup another virtual environment and install Django there again and report back. Thanks again

Comment: Okay so I'm getting the exact same error after installing Django again in a fresh virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problems occur when you don't include a path in virtualenv.

Try adding the path of python on your vscode.
Or, try to install and uninstall the Django projects.